# Android Close Second activity and move to first activity

Tags: android

I am in Second activity, doing uninstall other app works fine.

But when Uninstall finished, I want to kill the second activity and move to previous(First) activity. I don't Know how to do it.

Please He

```
btnUninstall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:" + packageInfo.packageName);
            Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
            startActivityForResult(uninstallIntent, 1);
        }
    });
```

Comment: wherever your uninstallation finished just call ActivityName.finish(); and try

Comment: But how? Detail please!!!!!!

Comment: try `intent.finish()` this should do the trick.

Comment: in your startActivityForResult or where your unistallation finished at that time call SecondActivity.finish(); @BalaRaja If you need more detail add your full code of  startActivityForResult and related code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I Implemented at the time of calling the Uninstall Intent i have saved the package name in a preferences file by using

```
SharedPreferences prefs;
prefs.edit().putString(DELETE_PACKAGE_NAME, packageName).commit();
```

And what i have done in OnActivityresult i have just checked whether the application with saved package name still present if it is means user has clicked on Cancel else he clicked Ok.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 

 if(requestCode==DELETE_APP){

    String requestedPackageName=prefs.getString(DELETE_PACKAGE_NAME, "");

    boolean isPresent=GCMIntentService.isAppPresent(requestedPackageName, this);

    if(isPresent){

      //user Clicked on Cancel
    }else{

      //user Clicked on Ok
    }


 }

}
```

Code for Checking the application presence

```
public static boolean  isAppPresent(String packageName,Context context) {


  try{
    ApplicationInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0 );
    return true;

} catch( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e ){

   return false;
}

 }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just finish your activity in onActivityResult as follows :

```
@Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

       if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           switch (requestCode){
               case 1:
                 // finish your activity
                 finish();
           }
       }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call an intent back to the first activity or finish the second activty intent from the onActivityResult callback in the second activity ,which will be called after the intent execution is over.